# Web forms to Razor view migration of enterprise application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I am a developer on a large scale enterprise web application that is utilizing a rapidly aging architecture so we have been discussing how best to approach modernizing the app. Specifically it is an ASP.Net 4.0 web forms application with MVC kind of stapled on top but it's still using all ascx views. Additionally we are using a database framework called Entity Spaces which has basically gone by the wayside in favor of Entity Framework. We are getting ready to migrate the application up to .net 4.6 so we are at least running a modern version but we have aspirations to one day be able to do extensive unit testing and test automation on the app which is currently not really possible because of the architecture.

My question then is does anyone have any good information or resources on how best to approach this problem? For example say we have an ASP.Net 4.6 web app with 10 areas under it. Would it be possible to pull an area out into it's own project and refactor it to use Razor Views and Entity Framework but still run in the same domain alongside the rest of the areas that have not yet been overhauled? Taking and refactoring the whole application in one go will never sell to upper management but if we can do it one module (area) at a time it's probably feasible. Any information about technical possibilities or problems we might face would be really helpful. I can't imagine other large enterprise applications haven't faced a similar issue, but I have found very little information on how to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem of migrating to MVC could have been solved if you had a DLL that contained all your business operations; then you would just consume them from a Razor backed MVC application instead of the Web Forms one.

The solution to your problem of migrating to EF could have been solved if you have used DIP (Dependency Inversion Principle) through-out the system; you would simply change the concrete implementations of your repositories/services/dao's to be EF adapters instead of Entity Spaces classes.

**Edit:**
But, since you have asked how do we move on from where we are right now;

- I'd say don't make the mistake you have done before. Separate your concerns, application code and business code are different things and should belong to different locations.
- Write Unit Tests, you have the code-base to easily come up with what tests to write.
- Follow [S.O.L.I.D. principles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oar-T2KovwE)

And on a micro level of migrating, I've done that with an application of mid-size I'd say. We have used classical DAO approaches and then we wanted to migrate to NHibernate. Our DAO approach used Stored Procedures so I had to write all that SP's with NH's Linq To SQL approach. We have dealt with the migration on a fairly short amount of time, but I was never sure if I've broken the whole thing. Very fortunately, I haven't broken the whole thing, and it did work on one of the first tries. But that's pure luck, if we had Unit Tests and Integratioın tests, it wouldn't have been luck to get it right the first time because we would get errors before we ran the thing.

So here is my process for that migration; first I've designed the common interfaces because I had written code in front of me. I would just extract the signatures from the DAO's and put them in separate interfaces. Then I would change the dependents of DAO'S (mainly business operations/services) to depend on the interfaces instead. Then I would write NHibernate concrete classes, and give them as concrete instances to the dependent systems.

So, as you can see, the very first step is to re-design the "interface"s, this is a good chance for refactoring your system on an architectural perspective. The second step is to change the dependencies. This is a good chance for asserting if you've done any wrong during the first step. And the third step is to implement the new system.

Comment: Thanks for the input, all sound advice. Unfortunately, I wasn't around for the original design of this application so the architecture problems are inherited. My main question though stems around whether it's possible to refactor one area of the application at a time. Basically can you have web forms ascx views and ravor view existing in harmony side by side through the transition? If so how would I go about it and what are the technical ramifications we would have to deal with in the process?

Comment: So you are considering running two applications at the same physical location? I don't think it'd be possible to make it a single project. You'd instead constantly update the two applications according to what parts are where. You could have some automation in this process, maybe some configuration that gives priority over to the MVC application for the route management, so that even when a page is left running in the old app, the users can't access it. By the way, take no offense on the "you" parts of my answer; I'm talking about the original author and the ones in charge of decisions.